# C# Forms - Label text changing with click events

Tags: c#, forms, text, edit, label

In C# forms application I have done the following:

```
Label Some; string S;
private void Something()
{
  Some.text = S;
  Some.Location = new Point(100, 100);
  Some.Size = new Size(300, 300);
  this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { Some });
}
```

Then I defined S with click events:

```
private void YARR_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  S="Some random text";
}
```

And another:

```
private void HARR_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  S="Some other random text";
}
```

Once created label "Some" does not change its text to value of "S" when I click those things... What am I missing?

Comment: You're setting the value of a textbox to the value of a string at that point in time - if you subsequently change the value of the string, the text in the textbox isn't changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are clicking is in the same Form as the Label you want to change the text, you just have to do

```
private void YARR_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Some.Text="Some random text";
}
```

Comment: @Antonio Teh Sumtin, Is your handler YARR_click being called at all?

Comment: Did work out eventually, had other problems in code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

please change the label text not assign value to string.

`do Some.text = "Some random Text"`  on click event or call `Something()` function in click event.

Comment: This sounds simpler... will try